# How to filter json data from array in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic2, ionic3, lodash

I am a beginner in Ionic 2. I have successfully fetch data from URL into an array.In my json response, there are multiple duplicate values. I have filter json response by using **lodash** command. But I am not getting a proper result which I required.Please give me solution for this.

**This is my json response:**

```
 {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Dahanu"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Tarapur"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Navapur"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Satpati"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Kelwa mahim"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Arnala"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Uttan"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Versova"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Marve-Manori"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Bandra"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Trombay"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Panvel (Ulva - Belapur)"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Mora"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Karanja (Rewas-Dharamtar)"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Mandawa"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Thane"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Bhiwandi"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Vasai"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
            "port_name": "Kalyan"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Thal"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Alibaug"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Rewdanda"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Borli-Mandla"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Nandgaon "
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Murud"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Dighi"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Mandad"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Kumbharu"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
            "port_name": "Shriwardhan"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Bankot"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Borya"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Dabhol"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Harnai"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Jaigad"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Kelashi"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Palshet"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Ratnagiri"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Varwade"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Aachare"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Devgad"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Purngad"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Vijaydurg"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Jaitapur"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Kiranpani"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Redi"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Niwati "
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Vengurla"
        },
        {
            "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
            "port_name": "Malvan"
        }
    ];
```

In this response most of **port_group** are same and every **port_name of port_group** is different

**This is .ts code**

```
var newJsonFile = _.uniqBy(jsonarray, 'port_group'); 
   //var filtered =  _.uniqWith(jsonarray, _.isEqual);
  this.information = newJsonFile;
```

This is i am getting after using this code
[image]

**I am getting the result:**

**Bandra Group Of Ports**

- Dahanu

**But I need this result:**

**Bandra Group Of Ports**

- Dahanu
- Tarapur
- Navapur
- Satpati
- Kelwa mahim
- Arnala
- Versova

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: think you are looking for [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#filter) or Array.prototype.filter without lodash

Comment: yes sir . i requited that result which is i mention above Bandra Group Of Ports

Dahanu
Tarapur
Navapur
Satpati
Kelwa mahim
Arnala
Versova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data based on `port_group`.

```js
var data = [{ "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Dahanu" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Tarapur" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Navapur" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name":"Satpati" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Kelwa mahim" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Arnala" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Uttan" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports","port_name": "Versova" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Marve-Manori" }, { "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Bandra" }, { "port_group": "Mora Group Port", "port_name": "Trombay" }, { "port_group": "Mora GroupPort", "port_name": "Panvel (Ulva - Belapur)" }, { "port_group": "Mora Group Port", "port_name": "Mora" }, { "port_group": "Mora Group Port", "port_name": "Karanja (Rewas-Dharamtar)" }, { "port_group": "Mora Group Port", "port_name": "Mandawa" }, { "port_group":"Mora Group Port", "port_name": "Thane" }, { "port_group": "Mora Group Port", "port_name": "Bhiwandi" }, { "port_group": "Mora Group Port", "port_name": "Vasai" }, { "port_group": "Mora Group Port", "port_name": "Kalyan" }, { "port_group": "Rajpuri Groupof Ports", "port_name": "Thal" }, { "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Alibaug" }, { "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Rewdanda" }, { "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Borli-Mandla" }, { "port_group":"Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Nandgaon " }, { "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Murud" }, { "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Dighi" }, { "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Mandad" },{ "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Kumbharu" }, { "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports", "port_name": "Shriwardhan" }, { "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Bankot" }, { "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports","port_name": "Borya" }, { "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Dabhol" }, { "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Harnai" }, { "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Jaigad" }, { "port_group": "RatnagiriGroup Of Ports", "port_name": "Kelashi" }, { "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Palshet" }, { "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Ratnagiri" }, { "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Varwade"}, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Aachare" }, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Devgad" }, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Purngad" }, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports","port_name": "Vijaydurg" }, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Jaitapur" }, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Kiranpani" }, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Redi" }, { "port_group":"Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Niwati " }, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Vengurla" }, { "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports", "port_name": "Malvan" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.port_group] = r[o.port_group] || {name: o.port_group, children: []};
      r[o.port_group].children.push({port_name: o.port_name});
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sir , How to get this result into array like this  information: any[];

Comment: Please share a sample output.

Comment: i want to show this in **accordion-list**  . its going difficult to copy this result into array

Comment: Do you want the array to be composed of an object with `name` and `children` as property?

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167600/discussion-between-harshal-deshmukh-and-hassan-imam).

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash's `_.groupBy()`, `_.map()` and `_.mapValues()`:

```
_(input).groupBy('port_group').mapValues(ps => _(ps).map(p => p.port_name));
```

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const input = [{
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Dahanu"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Tarapur"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Navapur"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Satpati"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Kelwa mahim"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Arnala"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Uttan"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Versova"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Marve-Manori"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Bandra Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Bandra"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Trombay"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Panvel (Ulva - Belapur)"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Mora"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Karanja (Rewas-Dharamtar)"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Mandawa"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Thane"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Bhiwandi"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Vasai"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Mora Group Port",
    "port_name": "Kalyan"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Thal"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Alibaug"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Rewdanda"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Borli-Mandla"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Nandgaon "
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Murud"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Dighi"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Mandad"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Kumbharu"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Rajpuri Group of Ports",
    "port_name": "Shriwardhan"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Bankot"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Borya"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Dabhol"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Harnai"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Jaigad"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Kelashi"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Palshet"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Ratnagiri"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Ratnagiri Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Varwade"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Aachare"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Devgad"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Purngad"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Vijaydurg"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Jaitapur"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Kiranpani"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Redi"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Niwati "
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Vengurla"
  },
  {
    "port_group": "Vengurla Group Of Ports",
    "port_name": "Malvan"
  }
];
const output = _(input).groupBy('port_group').mapValues(ps => _(ps).map(p => p.port_name));

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```